# ifelse in data.table aggregate result

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table

I have a question which really need your help:

```
set.seed(1111)
s<-rep(seq(1,4),5)
a<-runif(20,0.2,0.6)
b<-runif(20,0.4,0.7)
b[6:8]<-NA
c<-runif(20,4,7)
d<-data.table(s,a,b,c)
setkey(d,s)
```

The data is as following:

```
    s         a         b        c
 1: 1 0.3862011 0.4493240 6.793058
 2: 1 0.4955267 0.4187441 4.708561
 3: 1 0.4185155 0.5916827 6.810053
 4: 1 0.5003833 0.5403744 5.948629
 5: 1 0.5667312 0.5634135 6.880848
 6: 2 0.3651699 0.5263655 5.721908
 7: 2 0.5905308        NA 6.863213
 8: 2 0.2560464 0.4649180 5.745656
 9: 2 0.4533625 0.5077432 5.958526
10: 2 0.4228027 0.4340407 5.115065
11: 3 0.5628013 0.6517352 6.252962
12: 3 0.5519840        NA 4.875669
13: 3 0.2006761 0.6418540 5.452210
14: 3 0.5472671 0.4503713 6.962282
15: 3 0.5601675 0.5195013 6.666593
16: 4 0.2548422 0.6962112 5.535579
17: 4 0.2467137        NA 6.680080
18: 4 0.4995830 0.6793684 6.334579
19: 4 0.2637452 0.4078512 6.076039
20: 4 0.5063548 0.4055017 5.287291
```

If I do a simple sum, using s as key, it will return a nice table summarize the result:

```
d[,sum(c),by=s]

s       V1
1: 1 31.14115
2: 2 29.40437
3: 3 30.20972
4: 4 29.91357
```

However, if my data.table command contain `ifelse` statement, I will not get similar table:

```
 d2<-d[,ifelse(a<b,"NA",sum(c)),by=s]
 d2


 s               V1
 1: 1               NA
 2: 1 31.1411493057385
 3: 1               NA
 4: 1               NA
 5: 1 31.1411493057385
 6: 2               NA
 7: 2               NA
 8: 2               NA
 9: 2               NA
10: 2               NA
11: 3               NA
12: 3               NA
13: 3               NA
14: 3 30.2097161230631
15: 3 30.2097161230631
16: 4               NA
17: 4               NA
18: 4               NA
19: 4               NA
20: 4 29.9135677714366
```

Is that possible to use the `ifelse` statement return a result just like the simple sum result table which return the unique non-na value under the each index value?

Thanks a lot!!!!!

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Within each group, `a` and `b` are vectors, so `a<b` is a vector also. Look at group 1. Is `a<b`? Sometimes it is, sometimes not. So do you want `NA` or the sum? Maybe you want `all(a<b)`?

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I know why I am confused here.. So If I am understand rightly, the statement a<b for the whole vector will return a vector of true or false, there for the result will return row by row according to the true false in specific position in that vector. If I want summary, I need to use all(a<b) which gives a single logic value for the whole vector then the summary could be obtain. Is that right?

Comment: You must show your expected result. `ifelse` is behaving as it is designed to, so it's hard for us to tell what result you wanted to see.

Answer (score 3):

I am not entirely certain what you are looking for, but I think you just want to use the `a<b` condition as the row selector in your `data.table`, which is done by using it as the first argument in the brackets:

```
> d[a<b, sum(c), by = s]
s V1  
1: 1 19.6
2: 2 22.5
3: 3 11.7
4: 4 17.9
```

Comment: My understanding on the line `d2<-d[,ifelse(a<b,"NA",sum(c)),by=s]` in the question is that it is asking for sum of `c` for values where `a` is NOT < `b` because whenever `a < b`, it's NA. So it could be: `d[!a<b, sum(c), by=s]`

Comment: Thanks to both of you, even my self I get confused what I am trying to do. But you actually did what I want..I used to think the statement right after the `[` is only for the table joint use, but now I know it could be used as conditional statement. Really thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple and fast solution based on conditional sum using `which`:

```
d[, .( sum_c = sum(c[which( a < b)]) ), by=s]

#    s  sum_c
# 1: 1 19.552
# 2: 2 22.541
# 3: 3 11.705
# 4: 4 17.946
```

The advantage of this structure over the other answers presented so far is that it allows you to calculate different aggregations in the same call using different conditions, for example:

```
d[, .(  sum_c = sum(c[which( a < b)]),
        sum_a = sum(c[which( c < 6)]) ), by=s]

#    s  sum_c  sum_a
# 1: 1 19.552 10.657
# 2: 2 22.541 22.541
# 3: 3 11.705 10.328
# 4: 4 17.946 10.823
```

There is a benchmark of the speed of this solution compared to other approaches in a [similar question, here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37286882/aggregate-column-intervals-into-new-columns-in-data-table/37769497#37769497).

Answer (score 0):

```
  library(plyr)  
  ddply(d[a<b], .(s), summarize, tot=sum(c))
```